# List of MySQL C++ Connector error codes

Tags: c++, mysql

I am quite desperate trying to find the list of all the possible error codes throwed by the MySQL C++ Connector.

The class `sql::SQLException` has an error code number but I could not find a list of all the possible values. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching for "mysql error codes"?

Comment: I think it's the same as MySQL error codes. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was looking for this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html.